# I don't understand why I'm getting an index error, when trying to extract exif data

Tags: python-2.7, gps, exif

The code and error with sample data from an image:

```
image = Image.open(newest)
exif = image._getexif()
gps = {}
datebool = False
gpsbool = False
date = 'None'
time = 'None'
gpstext = 'None'
dmslat = 'None'
dmslon = 'None'

if exif is not None:
    for tag, entry in exif.items():                        #Import date and time from Exif
        datebool = True
        if TAGS.get(tag, tag) == 'DateTimeOriginal':
            date = entry[0:10]
            time = entry[11:19]
    for tag, entry in exif.items():                        #Check if the GPSInfo field exists
        if TAGS.get(tag,tag) == 'GPSInfo':
            gpsbool = True
            for e in entry:
                decoded = GPSTAGS.get(e,e)
                print (decoded)
                print(type(entry))
                gps[decoded] = entry[e]
```

The results

```
4984
<type 'tuple'>

Traceback (most recent call last):File"C:\Users\~~~~~\Desktop\project_7-8-2015\8_bands\Program_camera.py", line 109, in <module>
gps[decoded] = entry[e]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Since e is pulled from entry, how can indexing that particular e from entry generate an indexing error? Am I actually pulling the correct data for the gps?

Answer (score 0):

`for e in entry` doesn't index the values in entry, it iterates over them. For example:

```
entry = (3, 5, 7)
for e in entry:
    print(e)
```

will output:

```
3
5
7
```

So the line should probably look like:

```
gps[decoded] = e
```

though I'm not sure what the `GPSTAGS` line would become. If you really need the items in `entry` enumerated, then you should look into (to your great surprise, I'm sure) the `enumerate()` function.